# Azure Service Bus: should I close QueueClient on application shutdown?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an ASP.NET REST service that receives messages from a queue using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus library.

It has the next service bus queue messages consumer that instantiates `QueueClient` and starts listening to the messages from the queue:

```cs
public class ServiceBusConsumer : IServiceBusConsumer
{
    private readonly IQueueClient client;

    public ServiceBusConsumer()
    {
        client = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, ServiceBusQueue);
        client.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, ProcessErrorAsync);
    }

    // ...
}
```

My question is, how to dispose the instance of `QueueClient` *on application shutdown* correctly? Should I make the `ServiceBusConsumer` disposable and add a method like the below one to it, so that the dependency injection container would call it and dispose the `QueueClient`? Or the `DisposeAsync` is not needed?

```cs
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    await client.UnregisterSessionHandlerAsync(maxMessageHandlingTime);
    await client.CloseAsync();
}
```

My confusion is caused by the fact that the `QueueClient` itself implements neither `IDisposible`, nor `IAsyncDisposable`, which suggests that I am not expected to perform any additional steps on application shutdown. On the other hand, the `QueueClient` has the `CloseAsync` method that suggests that some actions may be required for the graceful shutdown.

[The official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk#reusing-factories-and-clients) only says that I should not close the `QueueClient` for every message, however, it does not say anything about closing `QueueClient` on application shutdown.

Comment: Given my experience of the Azure libraries and the associated documentation, I'd 100% err on the side of caution.

Comment: Closing seems to do [several things that are desirable](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/a17b3d3b60ccf80fad616ac17927983b7e306014/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/src/QueueClient.cs#L545)

Comment: @Liam, thank you for the quick answer and the link to the code! They indeed look like actions that should be performed before shutdown. It's now, however, even more confusing why isn't the `QueueClient` disposable itself? If it was disposable, then the dependency injection container would be able to take care of these "desirable" actions by itself.

Comment: Honestly, there isn't a day goes by where I don't find something wrong with the Azure SDK. It's generally quite buggy and parts are not well thought out. As to why they didn't do this, who knows. You could raise an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues) and see what the response was from MS? Join the queue of 1,500 people waiting for responses :D

Comment: @Liam, I think I've got your point. :) Going to call `UnregisterSessionHandlerAsync` and `CloseAsync` manually for now and create the ticket to them. Who knows, maybe I'm lucky and it will get resolved soon. :)